# how to Add TreeNode in Treeview in hierarchical order using Sql in winforms?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to add TreeNode in Treeview in Hierarchical order in winforms using sql.
Anybody, Please help me out.

Comment: What you mean by using SQL? are you trying to say Fetching data from SQl and binding it to tree view?

Comment: @BreakHead: yes , i want to fetch data from Sql and binding it to treeview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will help you [Using TreeView Control in C#](http://www.aspspider.com/resources/Resource293.aspx)